# Android unable to create directory: /tokens

Tags: android, gmail-api

I used the quickstart given by Google at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java to send an email without Intent using Gmail API. I already have OAuth 2.0 Client IDs for android.

for some reason when I run the program it gives me the error of:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.nls.myapplication22, PID: 3216

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /tokens
```

code (from quickstart):

```
String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";
[...]
    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
```

Gradle:

```
[...]
dependencies {
    [...]
    implementation("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1")
    implementation("com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev20220404-2.0.0")
    implementation("javax.mail:mail:1.4.7")
}
```

Comment: `TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens"` That is no path. Only a folder name maybe. You should provide a full storage path. `/this/is/a/path`.

Comment: Maybe, but it still doesn't solve the problem. If it cannot create "tokens", why would it create "/a/token/from/something/else"?

Comment: That looks like a path indeed. But it is no valid path for an Android device. You should choose the right storage location.